# Socket client how setSoTimeout

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need to set time for max connection time in a socket client. But if I do like the following code, does not work, because line one open a connection and is a blocking function and never run line two.

How can I setSoTimeout before open connection?

```
Socket s = new Socket(server.host, server.port);                
s.setSoTimeout(server.time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Socket socket=new Socket();   
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port),timeout);
```